# CompletableFuture - Exception Cause / Stack trace not available

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have an async application. By executing for example the async method getTest() I never get the full strack trace caused the error:

```
CompletableFuture<Test> test = myAdapter.getTest();
test.whenComplete((result, e) -> {
   if (e != null) {
      // do some stuff
   }
});
```

If an IllegalstateException is thrown, the strack trace is not available. The only thing I can see is that the CompletionException was caused by an IllegalstateException:

[image]

This makes it very hard to find out where for example a NullPointerException is coming from.

[image]

Comment: Are you certain your debugger isn't just hiding it from you? Have you tried logging it? What about suppressedExceptions? What is under those collections?

Comment: I see the `IllegalStateException` seems to itself be caused by an `IllegalStateException`. Perhaps expanding the nested cause will give you what you need?

Comment: @DavidConrad suppressedExceptions is empty.

Comment: @Slaw I do not know why, but I can go deeper and deeper and come never to and end (also not after expanding 50 causes). It is the same Id (see screenshot), so maybe a reference to it self? I only throw a IllegalStateException for testing this problem - that's all. I added an additional screenshot in the first post.

Comment: And what happens if you log it? Or just `e.printStackTrace()`?

Comment: @DavidConrad By logging I also receive not a stacktrace and only the message of the Exception.

Comment: Mhh... I tried a lot. Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Slaw the cause is pointing back to the same `IllegalStateException`. This is the way, the `Throwable` indicates internally that no cause has been set. @Thomas You should not use a debugger to inspect exceptions. As David Conrad suggested, `printStackTrace()` is the way to go. As the internals of a throwable may confuse you, the cause pointing to itself, the stack trace being an empty array, unless the stack trace is actually requested (through the actual official API).